# For each big group select the best sub-group available in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set which has a some big groups, and subgroups (small groups).

I want to select small group 1 for each big group. But, if small group one doesn't exist in big group, select subgroup 2. My example below stops here, but ideally this would continue to work, so if subgroup 2 is not found, select subgroup 3. etc. In the example I use numbers but my focus is on doing this with factor levels.

Is this possible with factors in dplyr? assuming the factor levels are ordered in terms of importance?

Here is my example data:

```
set.seed(123)
big_group = rep(1:3, each = 6)
small_group = c(sample(1:2, size = 6, replace = TRUE),
                rep(1, each = 6),
                rep(2, each = 6)) %>% 
  as.factor()

d = data.frame(big_group,
               small_group,
               value = runif(n = 3 * 6))
```

And the ideal output would be

```
big_group    small_group    values
1            1              0.52810549
2            1              0.67757064
3            2              0.32792072
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining both answers from @akrun and @KarolisKoncevičius you could also just do:

```
d %>%
  group_by(big_group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(small_group))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   big_group [3]
#>   big_group small_group value
#>       <int> <fct>       <dbl>
#> 1         1 1           0.528
#> 2         2 1           0.678
#> 3         3 2           0.328
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a `dplyr` solution but in R you can do:

```
do.call(rbind, by(d, d$big_group, function(x) x[which.min(d$small_group),]))

#   big_group small_group     value
# 1         1           1 0.5281055
# 2         2           1 0.6775706
# 3         3           2 0.3279207
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to do this without treating small group as a numeric though?

Comment: In this code there is nothing only-numeric about `d$small_group`. It should work with factors too. Consider this: `which.min(factor(c("C","B","D"), levels=c("A","B","C","D")))` - will correctly return `2`.

Comment: sorry - I had tried min in stead of which.min. my mistake

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'big_group', `filter` the rows having the `min` value for 'small_group', and then `slice` the first row

```
d %>%
   group_by(big_group) %>%
   filter(as.numeric(small_group) == min(as.numeric(small_group))) %>% 
   slice(row_number()==1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups: big_group [3]
#   big_group small_group value
#      <int> <fctr>      <dbl>
#1         1 1           0.528
#2         2 1           0.678
#3         3 2           0.328
```

---

Or use `match` with `slice`

```
d %>% 
  group_by(big_group) %>% 
  slice(match(levels(droplevels(small_group))[1], levels(droplevels(small_group))))
```

Comment: thanks - is it possible to work this without making small_group numeric though?

Comment: @SamPassmore  How do you find the minimum of small_group?

Comment: well that is the problem. How can I always select the highest level of a factor. I will make the question more explicit

Comment: @SamPassmore  Your point is not clear though.  I added a `match` based solution

Comment: @SamPassmore  If it is based on the levels, then do the `match` on the first level and `slice`

Comment: I do say 'is this possible to do with factors'. Which I think was pretty explicit. But I have edited the question to try and point out this focus.

Comment: @SamPassmore  I changed the code to the focus on `levels` in `match`  Hope it helps

Comment: @SamPassmore  When I added the `which.min` you said it is not the case,

Comment: I did not say that. But I do see you did offer the which.min result in your edits - you must have changed it before I saw it. I am happy to give you the answer if you change it back since you got it first.